# NMap Topologie missing Switches (no kind of Topology)

Tags: networking, nmap, topology

I did scan some of our Networks but for any reason NMap doesnt applies any kind of topologie.
It seems like there is everything connected directly but there are switches in between and those connections seem like not being recognized.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAyMe.png

It shouldnt look like this in any manner.
How can I adjust this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nmap is a *network* (layer 3) scanner, so it does network traceroute (with the `--traceroute` option) and will show *routers* along the path, but not switches. Switches are *link-layer* devices (layer 2), so they are completely transparent to network packets.

Comment: even if they are L3 switches ?